# When two functions touch

Tags: functions, logarithms

I have two functions:
$$\log P=e^{-2\pi\xi_{o}^{2}t}\frac{t}{\tau}$$
and
$$\log P=\left(E_{0}^{2}\tau t\right)^{-2}\frac{t}{\tau}$$
And they touch at some point, there's a transition of the first function to the second.
I want to know the time of transition, so I equalized the two functions and obtained:
$$e^{-2\pi\xi_{o}^{2}t}=\left(E_{0}^{2}\tau t\right)^{-2}$$
$$-2\pi\xi_{o}^{2}t=\log\left(E_{0}^{2}\tau t\right)^{-2}$$
$$-2\pi\xi_{o}^{2}t=-2\log\left(E_{0}^{2}\tau t\right)$$
$$\pi\xi_{o}^{2}t=\log\left(E_{0}^{2}\tau t\right)$$
I get to this. But i was supposed to get to the time of transition of:
$$t\approx\tau log(E_{0}\tau)$$
I don't understand what i am doing wrong.

These are functions i obtained from a decayment graph. $ξ_{0}$ is the coupling coefficient between a discrete state and a continuum of states, $E_{0}$ is the energy of the discrete state and $τ$ is the decayment time, where $τ=1/2π|ξ_{E}|^2$.

Comment: Where are you seeing this? Are there relationships between $\xi_0$, $E_0$, and $\tau$ that might be useful here?

Comment: These are functions i obtained from a decayment graph. $\xi_{0}$ is the coupling coefficient between a discrete state and a continuum of states, $E_{0}$ is the energy of the discrete state and $\tau$ is the decayment time, where $\tau=\frac{1}{2\pi\left|\xi_{E}\right|^{2}}$.

Comment: Good! You should put this information in your original question, not just as a comment.